# Get attribute value from xml tags with shell script and convert to csv

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell, ksh

**The task:**

I'm trying to get the attribute-value from xml tags with a shell script, split the value up and save them in a .csv-file.

This is how the xml looks like:

```
<host>
  <servers>
    <server name="Type1Name1-Port1" >...</server>
    <server name="Type2Name2-Port2" >...</server>
    <server name="Type3Name3-Port3" >...</server>
    ...
    <server name="TypexNamex-Portx" >...</server>
  </servers>
</host>
```

I'd like to get the values from the "name"-attribute and split them up like following:
`Type;Name;Port`

The output csv file I want should look like this:

```
Type1;Name1;Port1
Type2;Name2;Port2
Type3;Name3;Port3
...
Typex;Namex;Portx
```

**The problem:**

- I can't install anything on the server
- I can only use "ksh-awk" / "xmllint wihtout --xpath" / "standard linux commands"

I can use any shell-language I want to. I prefer bash and ksh.

**My questions:**

- Do you think it is possible to solve my task?
- What is the best approach for the sub-tasks? (reading, splitting, writing)

**EDIT:**

**Example data of a server-name:**

T-TTT_AAA-A-SSS-PPPP

Where T represents the Type, A the Applicationname, S the Server-Name, P the Port. The length of T, A and S are variable. P is constant.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible with a mix of `xmllint --shell` and `awk` or `sed`. What is the separator between your `Type1` and `Name1` ? Capitalization ?

Comment: Could you show an example using real data (or data that have a form similar than what you really have) ? This should be important for the awk part

Comment: @Aserre .. Done..

Comment: So, if you have `T-TTT_AAA-A-SSS-PPPP`, the output should be `T-TTT;AAA-A-SSS;PPPP`, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with, using only common tools : `xmllint` and `sed` :

```
echo 'cat //host/servers/server/@name' | xmllint --shell data.xml | sed -n 's: name=\"\([A-Z][a-z0-9]*\)\([A-Z][a-z0-9]*\)-\(.*\)\":\1,\2,\3:p'
```

The `sed` part is done according to OP's examples at the moment of posting.

**Breakdown:**

- `echo 'cat //host/servers/server/@name'` : we pass this command to `xmllint`. It will catch the `name` attribute of all the nodes inside `<host><servers><server ...> ... </server></servers></hosts>`
- `xmllint --shell data.xml` : iterates through `data.xml` and executes the commands passed as argument in an interactive shell.
- `sed -n 's: name=\"\([A-Z][a-z0-9]*\)\([A-Z][a-z0-9]*\)-\(.*\)\":\1;\2;\3:p'` : we process the output of `xmllint` to only keep the data we are interested

  - `xmllint` will produce the following output : `name="Type1Name1-Port1"`
  - We define 3 capture groups : a capital letter followed by any character except capital (for `Type`), another capital letter followed by any character except capital (for `Name`), and any character between the `-` and `"` character
  - We tell sed to only print the matched strings, separated by semicolumns

Output :

```
Type1;Name1;Port1
Type2;Name2;Port2
Type3;Name3;Port3
Typex;Namex;Portx
```

EDIT:

To fit the pattern you indicated in the comments, you'll just have to change the sed regex, for instance :

```
sed -n 's: name=\"\(.*\)_\(.*\)-\(.\{4\}\)\":\1,\2,\3:p'
```

This will match the format `T-TTT_AAA-A-SSS-PPPP`, with any length for  the type and server name. Try to fiddle around the regex or ask another question in the `regex` tag if this is not exactly what you need.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. But if there's another tag with the attribute "name", won't the ouput be falsified?

Comment: no, it will specifically look for the "name" attribute inside the <server> tag

Comment: But no part of the statement:
`sed -n 's: name=\"\(.*\)_\(.*\)-\(.\{4\}\)\":\1,\2,\3:p'`
says it has to be inside the <server> tag.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't matter, as it is executed after xmllint has extracted the data. So sed will execute the regex only after xmllint has extracted the `name` value from the `<server>` tags

Answer (score 1):

Without xmllint you can parse input like

```
<host>
  <servers>
    <server name="Type1_Name1-Port1" >...</server>
    <server name="Type-2_Name2-Port2" >...</server>
    <server name="Type3_Name-3-Port3" >...</server>
  </servers>
</host>
```

with

```
sed -n '/<server name=/ s/[^"]*"\([^_]*\)_\([^"]*\)-\([^"]*\)".*/\1;\2;\3/p' inputfile
```

Comment: Works. See accepted answer for a smaller statement with exact same ouput.

Answer (score 0):

```
xidel -e '//server/@name' f.xml |  sed ...
```